# Use ajax success data as variable in second ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script that makes two ajax calls - the second being contained within the success handler of the first.

However I need to use the data captured within the first success handler as a further variable to pass in the second ajax call and then use that variable within the php file that is undertaking the server side processing.

This is all very new to me, so I hope this makes some sort of sense. If anyone could assist that would be great.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 500000,
    url: 'processone.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success data from processone is " + data);
        var lead_id = data;

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        timeout: 500000,
        url: 'processtwo.php?lead_id'+lead_id,
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data2) {
            alert("success data from processtwo is " + data2)
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: So,What is the problem ?

Comment: So what is the problem? Your script doesn't work properly?

Comment: Not sure of your exact need (do you need to append the return from AJAX call 1 to the serialized form in call 2 or not?) but you have access to the _data_ variable in the 2nd ajax call, so you can do whatever you'd like with it.

Comment: Sorry - the script is working fine apart from the fact that the var is not being passed in the second ajax call

Comment: @user3091415 does no data at all reach the server the second call?

Comment: @veddermatic - that is exactly what I am trying to achieve

Comment: the second server call works well apart from the fact that the variable I am trying to pass from the success of the first server call  seems to not be working

Comment: @user3091415 how are you trying to receive that variable? `$_GET['lead_id']` or `$_POST['lead_id']`?

Comment: perhaps I should add that on the second server call I am attempting to  catch this variable in by php file with the following '$lead_id       = $_GET['lead_id'];' perhaps this is where is it going wrong?

Comment: @user3091415 Thanks for the clarification. I think I do what you need in an answer below, which is append the lead_id as a variable to the form data.

Comment: as per posts below I was missing an "=" sign after ?lead_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you lose a "=" sign in the code:

```
url: 'processtwo.php?lead_id='+lead_id,
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to split these into two separate functions and allow for a parameter to be passed to the second. Not really part of your question, but should make it much easier to read. The second process seems to be missing an equals sign in the url parameter which will cause it to not work

```
function processOne() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 500000,
    url: 'processone.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        //alert("success data from processone is " + data);
        //console logs are better to use when debugging data
        console.log('SUCCESS DATA', data);
        var lead_id = data;
        processTwo(lead_id);
    }
});
```

}

```
function processTwo(lead_id) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 500000,
    url: 'processtwo.php?lead_id=' + lead_id,
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data2) {
        alert("success data from processtwo is " + data2);
    }
});
```

}

If you're still not getting anything make sure the data is directly returning the `lead_id`. AJAX calls commonly return JSON data, so it very well might be something like `data.lead_id` or something like that. Alerts aren't useful for showing this so you could use the console log, `console.log('SUCCESS DATA', data)` to dig into the return data.

Comment: thanks for this @Josh. As per my comment on  the suggestion made by yalight the missing "=" sing was causing it to fail. That aside though, what is the benefit of splitting the code into two separate functions - does it simply make it easier to understand or are there any further benefits.

Comment: It's generally good practice, if that's all you're using it for then the only real benefit will be making it easier to understand. As your project grows though if you separate it out then you'll be able to reuse processOne and processTwo from other functions if needed. JavaScript can turn ugly quickly, so I'd argue that good organization and readable code is paramount. Glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 0):

Given the reply to my comment, and making the assumption that the `data` returned from the first AJAX call is a simple string value (if it's not, you can still use the code here to see how you need to do what you need to do). jQuery's `serialize()` returns a string (see https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) so you can just append to that.

Also, you are missing your `=` sign when making your URL, so if you are trying to get the lead_id as a GET var, that's why it's not working.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 500000,
    url: 'processone.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success data from processone is " + data);
        var lead_id = data;

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        timeout: 500000,
        // you are missing the equals sign here, which is why this doesn't work as a GET
        url: 'processtwo.php?lead_id'+lead_id,
        // here we tack on a lead_id variable to the serialized form and give
        // it the value you got back from query 1
        data: ($('form').serialize() + "&lead_id=" + lead_id),
        success: function (data2) {
            alert("success data from processtwo is " + data2)
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: this works great @veddermatic as an option to pass the var along with the serialized data - many thanks